# Not able to update table contents through postman using Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, postman

```
package com.shashank.topic;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Topic {

@Id
private String id;
private String name;
private String description;

public Topic() {
}

public Topic(String id, String name, String description) {
    super();
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.description = description;
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {

    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {

    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {

    this.name = name;
}

public String getDescription() {

    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {

    this.description = description;
}
}
```

Repository is configured like this

```
package com.shashank.topic;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

public interface TopicRepository extends CrudRepository<Topic, String> {



/***
 * CURD OPERATIONS
 * getAllTopics()
 * getTopic(String id)
 * updateTopic(Topic topic)
 * deleteTopic(String id)
 * */

 }
```

This is another class

```
package com.shashank.topic;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

@Service
public class TopicService {

@Autowired
private TopicRepository topicRepository;

public List<Topic> getAllTopics() {

    List<Topic> topics = new ArrayList<>();
    topicRepository.findAll().forEach(topics::add);
    return topics;
}

public Optional<Topic> getTopic(String id) {

    return topicRepository.findById(id);
}

public void addTopic(Topic topic) {
    topicRepository.save(topic);
}

public void updateTopic(String id, Topic topic) {
    topicRepository.save(topic);
}

public void deleteTopic(String id) {

    topicRepository.deleteById(id);
}
}
```

I'm able to post the topics in my table and get as well from the postman but when I try to use put, to update the contents of the table, nothing changes.

I was trying to put the below command to update the table

```
{
    "id": "javascript",
    "name": "Update javascript",
    "description": "Update javascript Description"
}
```

where "javascript" was already in the table, with name as "javascript" and description as "javascript description"

Here is my spring console log

```
2021-03-03 17:33:05.625  INFO 9848 --- [           main] 
com.shashank.CourseApiDataApplication    : Starting 
CourseApiDataApplication using Java 13.0.2 on DESKTOP-FGT8D3V with PID 9848 
(D:\MavenProjects\course-api-data\target\classes started by shash in 
D:\MavenProjects\course-api-data)
2021-03-03 17:33:05.628  INFO 9848 --- [           main] 
com.shashank.CourseApiDataApplication    : No active profile set, falling 
back to default profiles: default
2021-03-03 17:33:06.262  INFO 9848 --- [           main] 
.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA 
repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2021-03-03 17:33:06.290  INFO 9848 --- [           main] 
.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository 
scanning in 23 ms. Found 1 JPA repository interfaces.
2021-03-03 17:33:06.618  INFO 9848 --- [           main] 
o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 
8080 (http)
2021-03-03 17:33:06.623  INFO 9848 --- [           main] 
o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2021-03-03 17:33:06.624  INFO 9848 --- [           main] 
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache 
Tomcat/9.0.43]
2021-03-03 17:33:06.720  INFO 9848 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat]. 
[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2021-03-03 17:33:06.720  INFO 9848 --- [           main] 
w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: 
initialization completed in 1039 ms
2021-03-03 17:33:06.876  INFO 9848 --- [           main] 
o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing 
PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2021-03-03 17:33:06.901  INFO 9848 --- [           main] 
org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core 
version 5.4.28.Final
2021-03-03 17:33:06.964  INFO 9848 --- [           main] 
o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons 
Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
2021-03-03 17:33:07.016  INFO 9848 --- [           main] 
com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2021-03-03 17:33:07.018  WARN 9848 --- [           main] 
com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource  : Registered driver with 
driverClassName=org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver was not found, trying 
direct instantiation.
2021-03-03 17:33:07.269  INFO 9848 --- [           main] 
com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase          : HikariPool-1 - Driver does not 
support get/set network timeout for connections. (Feature not implemented: No 
details.)
2021-03-03 17:33:07.271  INFO 9848 --- [           main] 
com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2021-03-03 17:33:07.281  INFO 9848 --- [           main] 
org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: 
org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyTenSevenDialect
2021-03-03 17:33:07.911  INFO 9848 --- [           main] 
o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform 
implementation: 
[org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2021-03-03 17:33:07.916  INFO 9848 --- [           main] 
j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA 
EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2021-03-03 17:33:08.134  WARN 9848 --- [           main] 
JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled 
by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view 
rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this 
warning
2021-03-03 17:33:08.220  INFO 9848 --- [           main] 
o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 
'applicationTaskExecutor'
2021-03-03 17:33:08.460  INFO 9848 --- [           main] 
o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 
(http) with context path ''
2021-03-03 17:33:08.469  INFO 9848 --- [           main] 
com.shashank.CourseApiDataApplication    : Started CourseApiDataApplication 
in 3.207 seconds (JVM running for 3.973)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is something unusual with your Id. Why did you consider Id as String?
It should be `Long` or `int`, So maybe your id is your main problem.

Also, It would be better that put the controller to help us to debug better. Anyway, there are some ideas.

```java
public void updateTopic(String id, Topic topic) {
    Topic myTopic = topicRepository.findById(id);
    topicRepository.save(myTopic);
}
```

- Controller

```java
@PutMapping("/topics")  
private Topic update(@RequestBody Topic topic){  
topicService.updateTopic(topic);  
return topic;  
}
```

- Strongly recommend you to change your ID from string to `int` or `Long` and try the above solution.